# add More Lines in jQuery not work

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with jQuery. I want to make a dynamic Terms and Conditions Form
with More Lines and More Lines in content condition

Look at this image : [image]

I can add more condition lines and add more condition content lines in one condition only

can you help me ?

Here is the source code : http://jsfiddle.net/gsgw0bby/1/

```
                    $(".addNewLine").on('click', function(){
                    //e.preventDefault();
                     var abc = $('.addNewLine:first')[0];
                     var LineCond_Number = abc.getAttribute('id');
                     // var xyz = abc.getAttribute("data-lat");
                     //
                    if(ii_id < max_LiensConditions)
                    {
                        ii_id++;
                        $(".conditions_"+LineCond_Number+"_"+ii_id).append('<input style="width: 95%;margin-right: 3px;margin-top: 4px;background-color: #FFF;border-right: 1px solid #DDD;" name="display_price[content_condition]['+LineCond_Number+']['+ii_id+']" class="" type="text" /><div class="conditions_'+LineCond_Number+'_'+(ii_id+1)+'"></div>'); //add input box
                    }
                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: You have a number of problems in your code. You can fix the clicks using delegated event handlers, but the code does *not* change the DOM elements *relative to the item clicked*. That needs fixing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem:**

As the elements are dynamic, you need to use delegated event handlers, attached to a non-changing ancestor element. `document` is the default if nothing else is closer/convenient:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".addNewLine", function(){
```

**The second problem** is you are then accessing the same element via a selector, rather than `this`

```
    var abc = $('.addNewLine:first')[0];  <<< WRONG!!!
```

Do this instead:

```
    var $abc = $(this);
```

You then get an id from the element:

```
    var LineCond_Number = abc.getAttribute('id');
```

which could become the jQuery equivalent:

```
    var LineCond_Number = $abc.attr('id');
```

*After these issues I get a bit lost in your code* :)

Comment: thank you for help me .. but it's not working success 100%
Look : http://postimg.org/image/rooi7521d/
Edited : http://jsfiddle.net/gsgw0bby/4/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problems several times, and I learned thanks to here that, when you create a new td with the button, it doesn't triggers unless you specify from where it comes.

For example:

```
$("table").on("click", ".addNewLine", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Instead of `$(".addNewLine").on("click", function() {});`

Also check out, because I tried it and it adds it to the first td of new line.

Comment: This is not the only problem (by a long shot).

Comment: of course, the code need to be simplified and cleaned up.

Comment: I mean this is not the only fix required to make it work

Comment: Sure, as you said, he needs to point out `$(this)` on `abc` to make the line appear in the new td.